# How to split a data frame in R based on date when multiple rows have identical date stamp

Tags: r, dataframe, split

I had a number of large data frames which were all contained readings from different sensors over the same time period.

I have combined these using rbind to create one large data frame that I can use to make graphs, making use of the openair package and grouping by "Sensor Number"

The data I have looks like that shows below but covers a wide range of dates over 6 months. How can I create a new data frame that only keeps measurements from all sensors that was between two dates, for example 2021-06-10 until 2021-06-29.

```
    date              Sensor Number    Measurement
2021-02-01 00:15:00         1             1022
2021-02-01 00:30:00         1             1029
2021-02-01 00:45:00         1             1022
2021-02-01 01:00:00         1             1034
2021-02-01 01:15:00         1             1045
2021-02-01 01:30:00         1             1022
2021-02-01 01:45:00         1             1022
2021-02-01 00:15:00         2             1022
2021-02-01 00:30:00         2             1022
2021-02-01 00:45:00         2             1045
2021-02-01 01:00:00         2             1045
2021-02-01 01:15:00         2             1045
2021-02-01 01:30:00         2             1022
2021-02-01 01:45:00         2             1045
2021-02-01 00:15:00         3             1045
2021-02-01 00:30:00         3             1045
2021-02-01 00:45:00         3             1045
2021-02-01 01:00:00         3             1022
2021-02-01 01:15:00         3             1022
2021-02-01 01:30:00         3             1022
2021-02-01 01:45:00         3             1045
2021-02-02 00:15:00         1             1022
2021-02-02 00:30:00         1             1029
2021-02-02 00:45:00         1             1022
2021-02-02 01:00:00         1             1034
2021-02-02 01:15:00         1             1045
2021-02-02 01:30:00         1             1022
2021-02-02 01:45:00         1             1022
2021-02-02 00:15:00         2             1022
2021-02-02 00:30:00         2             1022
2021-02-02 00:45:00         2             1045
2021-02-02 01:00:00         2             1045
2021-02-02 01:15:00         2             1045
2021-02-02 01:30:00         2             1022
2021-02-02 01:45:00         2             1045
2021-02-02 00:15:00         3             1045
2021-02-02 00:30:00         3             1045
2021-02-02 00:45:00         3             1045
2021-02-02 01:00:00         3             1022
2021-02-02 01:15:00         3             1022
2021-02-02 01:30:00         3             1022
2021-02-02 01:45:00         3             1045
```

Comment: Just filter for where the date is greater than one bound and less than another. There should be other SO posts on doing that already, although your example will be hard to illustrate with since it only covers 2 days

Comment: `subset(dat, as.POSIXct("2021-02-01 01:15:00") <= date, date <= as.POSIXct("2021-02-01 11:30:00"))` will subset the data to between two timestamps, take that to the ends you need.